# Get percentage of two numbers declared as string in java

Tags: java

I have a JSP page with a small arithmetic calculation to make. The below block gives me a number (say 30)

```
Actor actor3 = new Actor();
            ResultSet actors3 = actor3.getActors3(userid);
            String Countrow2 = "";
            while (actors3.next()) {
                Countrow2= actors3.getString(1);

            }
```

I have another block which gives me another number (say 50)

```
Actor actor4 = new Actor();
            ResultSet actors4 = actor4.getActors4(userid);
            String Countrow3 = "";
            while (actors4.next()) {
                Countrow3= actors4.getString(1);

            }
```

I'm trying to use these numbers as integers to caluculate percentage like the answer should be (1-(30/50)*100) = 40%. so that I can print this value in a td element using the print.ln(). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Integer.parseInt("Countrow3");

Comment: be aware that, in terms of integral types, `30/50` will be `0`.

Comment: @NileshDeokar Thank you, but when i try it gives NumberFormatException: For input string: "Countrow". If it's because of String Countrow3 = "", then how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String num1 = "1";
String num2 = "3";
int num3 = (int) (Double.parseDouble(num1) / Double.parseDouble(num2) * 100);
System.out.println(num3 + "%");
```

output

```
33%
```